# Add application-specific dictionary to iPhone keyboard word completion functionality?

Tags: iphone, keyboard

In my iPhone application I want the standard iPhone keyboard word completion functionality to offer application-specific words when editing a UITextField. (How) can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this, if you want this functionality you should [file](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) a bug with Apple.